# iOS error 561145187 while App in the foreground

Tags: ios, crash, audiounit

I have an app using VPIO / RemoteIO Audio Unit. On certain iPad it crashed and throws an error code of 561145187.

After checking around, I found some say that starting IO in the background could cause this:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreaudiotypes/avaudiosessionerrorcode/avaudiosessionerrorcodecannotstartrecording?language=objc

However my app IS in the foreground, and it's 2021. This crash won't occur on iPhones and some Pads, but for certain iPads, e.g. the iPad Pro 2, it's guaranteed to occur.

Any similar experience and solutions?